# Unable to execute query against a linked server inside a SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My server setup is a bit weird. One of my DB Admins added a Linked Server to my server. In the linked server properties, I see the following in the Security view:

```
Local server login to remote server login mappings:

Local Login            Impersonate           Remote User              Remote Password
domain\myusername        CHECKED

For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:

- Be made using the security context
  Remote login: linkedserveruser
  With password: **************
```

Therefore, when I created a stored procedure with the following:

```
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP
FROM LINKEDSERVERNAME.DBName.dbo.TableName

-- Update local table after processing #TEMP
```

And setup a SQL job, it was failing with the following message:

```
Message
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. Login failed for user 'linkedserveruser'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456).  The step failed.
```

After, digging through documentation, I found a [KB811031](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811031) article that explains this problem and suggested that I map the security context and run the job as osql.

I did not have to map the security context because (as you can see from the settings of the linked server above), it already was mapped. I changed the Type to Operating System Command as suggested. When I run the job now, I get the following message:

```
Executed as user: domain\MYMACHINENAME$. Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server SOMEOTHERDATABASENAME, Line 1  Login failed for user 'linkedserveruser'.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.
```

And the job quits reporting success when in fact it failed. Any suggestions on how I can get this type of stored procedure containing a query to a linked server to run as a SQL job?

Comment: Are you sure that the password hasn't been changed for linkedserveruser? If that linked server was setup a long time ago, it's possible that the password has since changed. Maybe you can verify that the username/password is good by connecting directly to the linked server.

Comment: Did you try the other solution suggested in the KB article? That suggests altering the owner of the *JOB* to a sysadmin login (e.g. "sa") and is probably a much simpler solution.

Comment: @sl0ppy: Yes. I did try connecting to it directly and the queries work fine.

Comment: @Nathan: Yes. The surprising part is that it still gives me the same error `Executed as user: domain\MYMACHINENAME$ . Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server SOMEOTHERDATABASENAME, Line 1  Login failed for user 'linkedserveruser'.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.` Am I missing something?